# Asterisk AGI in PHPAgi process

Tags: php, asterisk

I have create an agi in php for my asterisk 11.3.0 and i have few agi calls stuck in queue when i use ps ux in my server it shows
`6:42 /usr/bin/php -q /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/php/myagi.php Unknown 190090`

Many processes like this stuck in queue.

All process with number like 
`0:00 /usr/bin/php -q /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/php/myagi.php 954332 190053`

I need to know how do i debug my agi if call from unknown number.

### My AGI Script

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
require('phpagi/phpagi.php');

$agi                = new AGI();

$calleridnum    = $agi->request['agi_callerid'];
$callerid       = $agi->request['agi_callerid'];
$callidname     = $agi->request['agi_calleridname'];
$phoneno        = $agi->request['agi_dnid'];
$channel        = $agi->request['agi_channel'];
$uniqueid       = $agi->request['agi_uniqueid'];

if(substr($phoneno,0,3)==011)
{
    $phoneno = substr($phoneno, 3);
}

$URL = '12121@mysip.abc.com';

$dialstr = "SIP/" . $URL;

$res = $agi->exec("DIAL $dialstr");

$dialstatus = $agi->get_variable("DIALSTATUS");
$answeredtime = $agi->get_variable("ANSWEREDTIME");


if($dialstatus['data'] != "ANSWER")
{
    //No answer
}
if($dialstatus['data'] == "ANSWER") 
{
    $agi->verbose("I am in Cutting Balance!!");
}
savecdr($URL,"$callerid", $phoneno, $trunk, $dialstatus['data'], $answeredtime['data'], $PerMinuteCharges,$callstart,$TriggerCharge,$OID,$callidname,$IP,$NodeID,$MinutesUsed,$TalkTime,$TTCut,$pTTRemain,$pHash[Expiry],$pMinTotal,$VOID);


$agi->hangup();

?>
```

Comment: What is the "Verbose" debug Output, when you add g to the Dial?

Answer (score 1):

To debug agi you need do following from ssh

1) Stop asterisk deamon

```
  asterisk -rx "core stop now"
```

2) Start asterisk in console(not detach) and start agi debug - all error will be shown

```
  asterisk -vvvvgc
  agi set debug on
  core set verbose 5
```

3) Check now. You have see all conversation between asterisk and your AGI script and all errors generated by script.

If still not help, also try "core set debug 5", but output will be hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore the SIGHUP signal when the channel is hung up ([Call Disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980183/call-disconnect-for-asterisk/14982283#14982283)).

Add `g` to the Dial:

`g: Proceed with dialplan execution at the next priority in the current extension if the destination channel hangs up.`

```
$agi->exec('DIAL', $dialstring.",30,g");
```

**AGI Debug**

You could print some debug messages in your Script:

```
// debug infos
$agi->verbose("before dial",3); 
// ...
$agi->verbose("Number: ".$argv[2]);
```

Connect to Asterisk (with Verbosity 3) :
 `asterisk -rvvv`

Use the CLI command agi show commands to list available agi commands.
`*CLI> agi show`

Watch AGI and your debug messages on the Asterisk CLI.
`*CLI> agi set debug on`

You could set your AGI Script verbose,
when "Unknown" is given and log to a file:

```
if ($argv[1] == "Unknown") {
  define ('VERBOSE', true);
} else {
  define ('VERBOSE', false);
}

if (VERBOSE) file_put_contents("/tmp/unknown.log", time().": ".$msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: No debug received in my file and still process stuck in queue when i run `ps ux` on my server many lines of phpagi.php with "Unknown" caller.

Comment: added agi scrip in question please have a look. all cals from unknown caller stucked in queue.